# PyQt QAbstractTableModel never updates when rows are added

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I've got a PyQt `QTableView`, hooked up to a `QAbstractTableModel`, which itself is hooked up to a custom class managing a list of items.  I can insert an item on the end of the list, and it appropriately notifies my model, which then calls `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows`.  I can verify that it calls both those functions, and the list has updated itself, but the table never calls `data` to retrieve the updated rows.

What's going on?  How can I fix it?

```
class FigureTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)

        def changed(index):
            start_index = self.createIndex(index, 0)
            end_index = self.createIndex(index, COLUMNS - 1)
            self.dataChanged.emit(start_index, end_index)

        def adding_row(index):
            self.beginInsertRows(self.createIndex(0, 0), index, index)
            print 'adding ', index

        def added_row(index):
            self.endInsertRows()
            print 'added'

        figures.dataChanged.connect(changed)
        figures.rowAdding.connect(adding_row)
        figures.rowAdded.connect(added_row)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(figures)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return COLUMNS

    def data(self, index, role):
        print 'in data'
        if not index.isValid():
            return EMPTY

        return figures[index.row()].get_table_item(index.column(), role)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one issue, which I think is the cause of your problem. It's about line:

```
self.beginInsertRows(self.createIndex(0, 0), index, index)
```

`self.createIndex(0, 0)` will create a valid `QModelIndex`. That refers to `parent` in [`beginInsertRows`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows), so you are basically telling the view that you'll be adding a  child to the first row in the table. Since the table has no concept of children (it's not hierarchical), it doesn't do anything.

For a table, `parent` should be an invalid `QModelIndex`, meaning your items are at the root. So, you should use:

```
self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), index, index)
# or depending on how you import
self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), index, index)
```

That being said, there are a couple of things that struck me as odd.

First, outside of the `index` method, you generally should avoid calling `createIndex` directly. Otherwise it's easy to mess things up. `index` method itself should provide a consistent way of creating `QModelIndex` instances. In your case, since you inherit `QAbstractTableModel`, `index` method is already implemented.

Second, you are using global variables. A lot. It's generally considered bad practice. If your class needs them, then pass them to `__init__`. For instance, right now you can't instantiate two independent models. Because they'll both use the same global `figure` variable. Or, I don't know what `EMPTY` refers to but `data` should simply return `None` for invalid types. No need for another name. Similarly you should be able to get `COLUMNS` from `figures` or if you need an explicit value, you should pass that to `__init__`.

Comment: Good to know about `index` and `createIndex`.  That's not very clear from the docs.  As for the globals, `COLUMNS` and `EMPTY` are both basically static constants (`EMPTY` is an invalid `QVariant`, as per the docs).  And the global `figures` is there because `figures` is a singleton; there's only one of these tables in the UI.

Comment: @ChrisB.: About `createIndex`... There is technically nothing wrong with using it anywhere, but there is not much reason to do so. Usually the `index` and `parent` are the only ones that need to create a `QModelIndex`. Other methods can ask these methods for indexes.